# How do I start a new game when a save file already exists?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-x-y

How do I delete my save data and start over? My brother grabbed hold of my 3DS when I wasn't looking, and I now have twice as many Pokedex entries, all named such travesties as Purkachurrr, Panpurrr, Durnspurrrrr, and Metapod (an Azuril, mind).

Since I was maybe only 20 minutes in, I think it might be best (for my sanity if nothing else), to just start the game over. But I can't find a way to start a new game! The main menu only lets me continue on the current save file.

Is there a way to handle this in game, or should I be deleting data from the main 3DS OS instead?

Comment: looooooooooooool

Comment: Purkachurrr use thunder bolt

Answer (score 29, accepted):

At the opening sequence, press the following button combination: `Up + B + X`. This should prompt you for deleting your save file.

The `Up + B + Select` no longer works on the X/Y series at the main menu, the button combination **must be** done at the opening movie sequence.